# Change property of a Jquery object?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a Facebook-like autocomplete jquery library found at:

http://otisbean.com/dropbox/jquery.tokeninput.js

In my own html code, I have the following which works fine

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#my_input_field").tokenInput("http://mysite.com/channel/1", {
                        classes: {
                                tokenList: "token-input-list-facebook",
                                inputToken: "token-input-input-token-facebook"
                        }
                });
        });

</script>
```

However, I want to create an html button that when clicked, will change http://mysite.com/channel/1 to http://mysite.com/channel/2.

So in my html button looks something like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="$('#my_input_field').url = 'http://mysite.com/channel/2'" />
```

That didn't work because .url property is not defined.  I don't know how to find the relevant property of this object.  How do I debug all this?  Can anyone offer suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: is http://mysite.com/channel/1 the value of the href attribute ?

Comment: At the moment, it's a hardcoded string to a url that will spit out json response for the autocomplete field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up.  I just hacked the original JS script and rewrote parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your URL in a variable, and reference that variable instead. Then, at any point, you can update that variable to point to a different URL:

```
url = "http://mysite.com/channel/1";

$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#my_input_field").tokenInput(url, {
                classes: {
                        tokenList: "token-input-list-facebook",
                        inputToken: "token-input-input-token-facebook"
                }
        });
});
```

Then on your button, have this:

```
<input type="button" onClick="url='http://mysite.com/channel/2';" />
```

Comment: It appears the object received the value of url as opposed to the reference to the url variable.  So even if I click the button, the object url property is still going to http://mysite.com/channel/1 .  Is there a way for me to force it to pass by reference?